# Java: Dynamic Layout using Eclipse Windowbuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, dynamic, windowbuilder

I'm working on a Java project (for those curious, it's a Rcon and Query client for Minecraft servers) and I'm trying to create a GUI. I'm using Eclipse Windowbuilder, and I'm trying to make the program window dynamic (in other words, when the window is resized, everything else moves and scales to fit), but none of the layouts seem to do that (which defeats the purpose of the layout, doesn't it). It's worth mentioning that I'm putting four groups on the screen, which will contain other things and should take up all available space. I would put the code here, but there's nothing besides the default application framework generated by Eclipse. So, what layout do I use for dynamic resizing and such? Or am I missing something stupid?

(P.S. I've tried GridLayout, FormLayout, and many others. They didn't work.)

Comment: Used correctly pretty much any of the layouts will work correctly with resizing. GridLayout certainly will.

Comment: Please define "used correctly". I created a window, I set the layout to GridLayout, I put groups in the grid, and they didn't resize to be bigger or smaller. I don't know how to do it any simpler.

Comment: Read something like [this tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize there were so many properties that had to be set. TBH Windowbuilder should default to these, or at least make the option more obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is for Eclipse Windowbuilder users.

For this to work (assuming `GridLayout` is used) you must set several properties for *every single thing* in the `GridLayout`:

- `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` should be `true` (check the box)
- `grabExcessVerticalSpace` should also be `true` (again, check the box)
- `horizontalAlignment` should be set to `FILL` (selected from drop-down)
- `verticalAlignment` should also be set to `FILL` (also selected from drop-down)

Thanks to [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) for giving me [this link](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm), which solved the problem.